# Understanding function signature

Tags: haskell, arguments, pattern-matching

I was reading [a paper](https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=bGlja21hbi5jb218cGF1bC1saWNrbWFufGd4OjE0N2MzOGEzZWY4YmM2YjI) and one of the most fundamental parts of it is the following function, written in Haskell:

```
fixP :: Eq a => (Parser a -> Parser a) -> Parser a
fixP h x = fixS f 
           where f s = h p x 
                       where p y = if x == y then s
                                             else fixP h y
```

My Haskell is rusty. As I understand it `fixP` takes 1 argument which is a function `Parser a -> Parser  a`, where `a` is constrained to have equality defined. However the pattern matches 2 arguments, `h` and `x`. What is `x` referring to?

Additional type signatures involved:

```
type Parser a = State -> Set (a,State)

type State = String

type Set a = [a]

fixS :: Eq a => (Set a -> Set a) -> Set a
```

---

After reading and understanding the answer and for anyone interested; here's the same function written in javascript:

```
function fixP(h) {
    return function(x) {
        var f = function(s) {
            var p = function(y) {
                if(x == y) {
                    return s;
                } else {
                    return fixP(h)(y);
                }
            };
            return h(p)(x);
        };
        return fixS(f);
    };
}
```

Comment: Is perhaps `Parser a` a function type (by which I mean `type Parser a = Something -> a`, or similar)? Since `fixP h` has type `Parser a`, it will then itself be a function, so it can take that `x`.

Comment: @gspr I have ammended my question with all type signatures involved.

Comment: Right, your edit clears things up. Since `type Parser a = State -> Set (a, State)`, the type of `fixP h` is `State -> Set (a, State)`. Now you see that it is in fact a function, so it makes sense to pass it an argument, i.e. to speak of `(fixP h) x` when `x :: State`. The associativity of function application makes this the same as `fixP h x`.

Comment: @gspr would you mind writing that as an answer, maybe a little more elaborated so I can accept it?

Comment: Alright. Let me know if you wish for further eleboration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `fixP h` has type `Parser a`. Since `Parser a` is a synonym for `State -> Set (a, State)`, we see that `fixP h` is in fact a function:

```
(fixP h) :: State -> Set (a, State)
```

We can therefore apply this function to some argument `x` of type `State`. That looks like `(fixP h) x`. Since [function application is *left associative*](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html) , `(fixP h) x` is the same as `fixP h x`.

In words: To define what `fixP` is, we define what it does to arguments, i.e. we define what `fixP h` is. Since `fixP h` is itself a function, we need to define it. We define it by specifying what it does to arguments, i.e. we define what `(fixP h) x` is. Left associativity of function application means the latter can be written `fixP h x`.

As to the question "what's x?": Its type is `State`, so it smells like some sort  of parser state, which according to the type synonyms you gave is a string. Exactly what that string's role is, though, is not clear just from the types :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanation: `Parser a` is a `type` like this:

```
type Parser a = (String -> a)
```

This code then

module Main where

```
type NT a = (Int -> a)

f :: (NT a -> NT a) -> NT a
f h x = undefined

g :: NT Double
g 0 = 0.0
g _ = 1.0

main = undefined
```

typechecks well.

Comment: Hi. Would you mind elaborating a little more or addressing the original question "What is x referring to?". Thanks in advance.

Comment: `x` is referring to `State`